# This and that difference

Tags: difference, pronouns

Are this and that both used to refer the thing/person/situation just mentioned or not?please help me in this or that.

E.g,

Two persons are talking about a man. That/this man is not on the spot. The first person tells the second person that I will find out the man who did this or that. The second person replies "How will you find this or that man?

Please tell me where should I use this and where that.

Comment: But the man is not on the spot they just talk about that.

Answer (score 1):

***Generally,*** 'this' is for the current situation and for something that is nearer to you. Opposite to that is 'that' - more distant and/or away in time.

If someone has broken the glass and those people are standing on the *spot,* they may say -

> "I'll find out the man who did **this.**

The broken glass is right there, so, 'this.'

But, the same people are away from the *spot,* they may say -

> "I'll find out the man who did **that.**

The broken glass is away, so, 'that.'

About a person, of course, he's away. Thus, ...

> How will you find *that* person/man?